# Prove two admissible functions sum is admissible and that an admissible multiplied by a constant is admissible.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If f and g are admissible functions on Rn and c is an element of R, show that f+g and cf are admissible.  I know that to be admissible the function must be continuous on a negligible set, bounded and have bounded support.  I can easily prove continuity for these problems but I am unable to come up with the other two parts of the proof to finish the question.